# Python code giving different output when `print` is used and when `print` is not used

Tags: python-3.x

I am practicing python coding on idle

I have the following code:

```
names=["Mark","John","July"]
names[0]
```

Output:

```
'Mark'

print(names[0])
```

Output:

```
Mark
```

Why in case of first output there are single quotes while in case of second output there are no single quotes?

Comment: because names[0] is accessing the 0th element in the list so it returns the string 'Mark' whereas `print()` in Python 3 is a function and it print object(s) to the stream file and All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream. So string like `Mark` appears like `Mark` in your output stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you just type a variable name in IDLE and press Return, it shows you how the variable "*looks like*" (or a `NameError` if the variable isn't defined). On the other hand, `print()` *displays* the variable.

Note: You can also *display* how the variable *looks like* by typing `print(repr(names[0]))`. That will print the string with its surrounding quotes.